# How do I re-position a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how would I re-position a drop-down menu.

What I am trying to achieve is a fake search. So when you click the search button, it activates a drop down with fake dummy results. I am trying to re-position the drop-down to make it look like it came from the search.

Here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/judison/45f50ws9/

```css
.searchBar {
  background-color: #67B4AD;
  color: white;
  width: 280px;
  border: none;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  right: 100px;
}
.add-on .dropdown > .btn {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  color: white;
  background-color: #67B4AD;
}
/* stop the glowing blue shadow */

.add-on .form-control:focus {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #67B4AD;
}
```

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="searchBarPadding form-group">
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input style="height:22px;" type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder=" &nbsp; Search">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button style="height:22px;" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="height:10px;"></i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I would really appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a very basic example that you can build off of

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/xwEXpv

Just added a click event to the `.dropdown-toggle` that will fade in the dropdown and removed the relative postion on

```
.input-group-btn,
.dropdown{
  position:initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're trying to accomplish. You can attach the button with an add on and adjust the width of the `dropdown-menu` to the `form-control` class so they are the same total width.

```css
#searchForm .form-control {
  background-color: #67B4AD;
  color: white;
  width: 280px;
  border: none;
}
#searchForm .dropdown-menu {
  width: 320px;
}
#searchForm .btn.btn-default {
  border: 1px solid #67B4AD;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  color: white;
  background-color: #67B4AD;
}
/* stop the glowing blue shadow */

#searchForm .form-control:focus {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #67B4AD;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #searchForm .form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #searchForm .dropdown-menu {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" id="searchForm">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a>

              </li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">CSS</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>

              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /btn-group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```